# Downloading nested pdf files with wget

Tags: linux, wget

I am trying to download dozens of PDF files located on pages linked from here:

http://machineknittingetc.com/passap.html?limit=all

Each PDF is referred to by a URL ending with `/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/[some three digit number]/`.

I have tried these:

```
wget -r -l2 -A.pdf http://machineknittingetc.com/passap.html?limit=all
wget -r -l2 -np http://machineknittingetc.com/passap.html?limit=all -A "*.pdf"
wget -r -l2 -np http://machineknittingetc.com/passap.html?limit=all -A "*.###"
```

It doesn't get the PDFs.

Does it have something to do with the server not being indexed to allow me to access the URLs like a file hierarchy? Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rajaganesh87 
 you are guessing at the directory link numbers and are your code does not work for the actual links needed per the base link http://machineknittingetc.com/passap.html?limit=all
and the (.pdf) files correlating to it.

The problem is your being blocked by the

> robots.txt file

and your using the dot (.) in

```
    -A .pdf
```

Try the code below that I tested and it works.

```
 wget -np -nd -r -l2 -A pdf -e robots=off http://machineknittingetc.com/passap.html?limit=all
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you ?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {000..175}
do
     wget  http://machineknittingetc.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/$i
done
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! But it gets a lot more than the links on that page. Apparently the downloadable subpath has a lot of files. I will look for a range for the files I want (hopefully they are not randomly numbered) and see if I can alter it.

Comment: I really should have thought of that.

Comment: No, it seems the files I want are not numbered predictably. Some are consecutive but then they start to jump around. Short of passing it a list of each file path, this will not work. Is there no way to do it with the wget filters?

Comment: @Kallaste In that case get the html using wget and grep for the document numbers, download again from that list